# Woo Commerce product image in the product page is too big.

Tags: woocommerce

At first, lightbox was not working then I searched and found that the updating product-image.php to the latest version will correct it.

After updating the file, lightbox started working but the image is too big in the product page and it is messing with the product description and all. 
A user cannot see details without scrolling down.

I am also sharing a screenshot here 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGLP5.jpg

How to reduce the size, I searched but haven't found anything. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think a link to the website would be more helpful than a screenshot, that way we could check the html/css code. has your theme the option to change the image size? or regenerate the thumbnails?

Comment: Here is the link of the website, - https://www.urbangawar.com/shop/shit-happens-chai-helps/

Comment: And yes my theme can regenerate thumbnails, Its woo-commerce responsive theme.